# Substring Issue: Substring converting to char

Tags: c#, string, char, substring

I am making a typing game and I need to make a list of each character in a string so I can define what input the code should be expecting.

I tried:

```
static List<char> chars = "This is my string".ToCharArray().ToList();
```

But because char does not contain capitalization information it throws this error:

*ArgumentException: InputKey named: T is unknown.*

I knew char was not going to work, I needed each letter to be a string, not a char. So, I created a method using Substring:

```
static List<string> ToStringArray(string input)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        strings.Add(input.Substring(i, 1));
    }
    return strings;
}

static List<string> strings = ToStringArray("This is my string");
```

But apparently Substring is converting to a char because my code is still throwing the same error, and if I change the length of the substring to 2 my code works again. How can I force Substring to not convert to char? Or should I be approaching this problem in a completely different way?

Comment: What throws error ? the first line definitely doesn't,. although you can shorten the first line by `List<char> chars = "This is my string".ToList();`

Comment: "But because char does not contain capitalization". `Char` has many static methods such as `IsUpper` which gives you the capitalization information. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper.aspx So no need to convert them all to strings again. Also I'm not really sure what the error is because I don't see "InputKey" anywhere.

Comment: What is "it"?  The line above your error does not throw that error, so what is doing it?

Comment: I was mistaken about which part of my code was throwing an error. It's my Input.GetKeyDown that detects the user input that is causing an issue. Thanks for pointing out my silly oversight it has led me to they way I need to approach the problem. I will use an if statement to detect capslock is on or shift is being pressed when it needs to be. I will post my code once I have it all written out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be approaching this from a more complex angle than it needs to be.

If you have a:

```
string testString = "This is my string";
```

Then you can already access each individual character by index, such as `testString[1]` (which would be 'h')

If you're worried about case, then you can reference the string with

```
testString.ToLower();
```

Comment: Accessing a string by index returns a char. Your solution to use ToLower would strip away any capitalization information which I need to preserve. If I don't my typing game will accept lower and upper case letters as if they are the same input.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information, in your question, then.  It's currently unclear as to what you're trying to accomplish.